# Get ListBox SelectedItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I feel like this should be a simple feature but I don't know how to bind to the selected items in a Listbox without using code behind.

I have a Listbox with Datatemplate containing a Checkbox. I want to get the list of the checked/selected items. How do I do this?

If I cannot get the SelectedItems, I want to bind to something that triggers "SelectedProduct" every time something gets selected so I can iterate through the "ProductList" and find the checked items. However, SelectedItem does not trigger every time I click on an item.

Here is my code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding ID}" Margin="2"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>

<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

A normal rational person would think `SelectedItems` should be bindable. Except... it isn't. And that *sucks*.

You have already hit on the usual approach, bind `IsSelected` to a property in your data object, then do something like:

```
myCollection.Where(i => i.Selected);
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) `SelectedItem` can return *any* selected item if the mode is set to "Multiple", so its trigger timing semantics are going to be undefined at best. Getting a notification when *any* part of the selection changes is going to be tricky, but you can always run logic when the `Selected` property gets changed (for example, raise an event the VM listens for).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interactivity extension:

Add the reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll using reference wizard, search in Extensions section.

Then include the following namespace in your xaml:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

And you can do this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FooList">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FooCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=FooList}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

In your ViewModel create a ICommand that get the current selected items.