# Get SelectedItem or SelectedItems in a ListBox that is updated to bind to ViewModel using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a WPF Network Scanning application using .NET Framework 4.7.2 with Caliburn Micro and a strict MVVM pattern. I have been going through all the similar questions to this one but yet to find a solution. I don't use code-behind and so I am trying to do everything MVVM style.

My ListBox is initially empty and items are added to it until my scan is complete. After this I try to select 1 OR multiple items in the ListBox even though visually the items can be multiply selected, the problem I am finding is that I am unable to bind SelectedItem in my ListBox View with the SelectedItem property. I.e. SelectedItem property in my ViewModel will not update and remains at null.

I want my SelectedItems collection to increment as more items are selected.

I have tried the following:

[Binding the IsSelected property of ListBoxItem to DataContext of Itemssource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640305/binding-the-isselected-property-of-listboxitem-to-datacontext-of-itemssource)

[Get ListBox SelectedItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237852/get-listbox-selecteditems)

These have not worked so far.

Example Model:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    protected int _id;
    protected string _name;
    public ExampleModel()
    {

    }
    public ExampleModel(int _id, string _name)
    {
        this.Id = _id;
        this.Name = _name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Name == Name && this.Id == Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Example ViewModel:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : Screen
{
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    public ExampleViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        // Initialize collection
        BindableCollection<ExampleModel> SelectedItems = new BindableCollection<ExampleModel>();
        _events = events;
    }

    private BindableCollection<ExampleModel> _selectedItems;

    public BindableCollection<ExampleModel> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return _selectedItems; }
        set
        {
           // SelectedItems remains NULL
            _selectedItems = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }

    private ExampleModel _selectedItem;

    public ExampleModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            // CODE NOT UPDATING SELECTED ITEM VALUE!
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItems);

        }
    }

    // Initialize list
    private HashSet<ExampleModel> _exampleList = new HashSet<ExampleModel>();

    public HashSet<ExampleModel> ExampleList
    {
        get { return _exampleList; }
        set { _exampleList = value; }
    }

    private async Task AddItem(ExampleModel item)
    {
        // A task to asyncrhonously add unique items to list
        await Task.Run(() =>
        _exampleList.Add(item));
        Items = new BindableCollection<ExampleModel>(_exampleList);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
    }

    private BindableCollection<ExampleModel> _items;

    public BindableCollection<ExampleModel> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }

    // Begin adding items to list
    public async void Add()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            // do something
            var item = new ExampleModel
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                Name = i.ToString()
            };
            await AddItem(item);
        }
    }

    // Button to start process
    public void Start()
    {
        Add();
    }

}
```

Example View:

```
        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                Margin="8 0 0 0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding  Path= Items}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                b:SelectedItemsBehavior.SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Id -->
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Id}"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                />

                            <!-- Name -->
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="10"
                                />              
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>                    
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Selected Items Behavior class:

public class SelectedItemsBehavior
{

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItems",

         typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(IList), OnSelectedItemsChanged));

    public static void SetSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, INotifyCollectionChanged value)
    {
        d.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public static IList GetSelectedItems(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (IList)element.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d,
                      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IList selectedItems = null;
        void CollectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.OldItems != null)
                foreach (var item in args.OldItems)
                    if (selectedItems.Contains(item))
                        selectedItems.Remove(item);

            if (args.NewItems != null)
                foreach (var item in args.NewItems)
                    if (!selectedItems.Contains(item))
                        selectedItems.Add(item);
        };

        if (d is MultiSelector multiSelector)
        {
            selectedItems = multiSelector.SelectedItems;
            multiSelector.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (d is ListBox listBox)
        {
            selectedItems = listBox.SelectedItems;
            listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
            listBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (selectedItems == null) return;

        if (e.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            (e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged
                           -= CollectionChangedEventHandler;
        if (e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            (e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged
                           += CollectionChangedEventHandler;
    }

    private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as DependencyObject;
        if (!GetIsBusy(s))
        {
            SetIsBusy(s, true);
            var list = GetSelectedItems((DependencyObject)sender);
            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
                if (list.Contains(item)) list.Remove(item);
            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
                if (!list.Contains(item)) list.Add(item);
            SetIsBusy(s, false);
        }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsBusy", typeof(bool),

              typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    private static void SetIsBusy(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value);
    }

    private static bool GetIsBusy(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsBusyProperty);
    }
}
```

I expect SelectedItems collection to populate, but the output remains null.
I expect when any item is selected the value of SelectedItem is updated but get null.

Comment: Have you decided what do you prefer, to check a box to indicate a selection or just to select it as list boxes work?

Comment: To select it as list boxes work...so I can remove the checkboxes but the issue would still remain.

Comment: Do you need the collection to update everytime you select someone? Or is there a button to make the thing once the items have been selected? The easiest way would be to use: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckListBox or you can get the source code.

Comment: The collection should update everytime an item is selected, e.g. if I select three items, the collection should hold 3 items. If I deselect one of them, the collection should go down to 2. I do plan to add a button to my UI that will enable me to do something with the collection  of selected items, but that's not necessary right now.

Comment: @AlbertAlonso Thank you for the tip on Xceed WPF Toolkit. After trying with the CheckListBox:
            
`<xctk:CheckListBox  
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
                Margin="8 0 0 0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Height="250"
                SelectedMemberPath="IsSelected"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`

**Now my SelectedItems collection holds the first selected item in the list**
Better than b4 but still :(.